# Localizing WPF controls through code behind

Tags: wpf, c#-4.0, localization

I have a WPF application which needs to support localization. I have 2 buttons (add, delete) and a combo box (english, french). When I select french, button's content should change to (ajouter, effacer).

Now, my question is, what would be the downside or drawback if I manually set the buttons content in code behind? See code below.

```
private void comboBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
  ResourceDictionary currentLanguage = new ResourceDictionary();

  switch (comboBox.Text)
  {
    case "english": 
      currentLanguage.Source = new Uri("../en-US.xaml", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
      break;
    case "france": 
      currentLanguage.Source = new Uri("../fr-FR.xaml", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
      break;
  }

  btnAdd.Content = Resources.GetString("insert");
  btnDelete.Content = Resources.GetString("delete");
}
```

I know its kind of weird but kindly answer it. Why shouldn't I localize my application this way.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When swapping resource dictionaries you should utilize using `DynamicResources` instead of `StaticResources` Basically in XAML you would do the following:

#### XAML

```
  <Button Content="{DynamicResource Insert}"/>
  <Button Content="{DynamicResource Delete}"/>
```

Where Insert and Delete are in your Resource Dictionaries using the x:Key

When you swap the dictionary then these will dynamically update

Comment: Hi MyKuLLSKI, thanks for your reply and answer. Can you explain why should this approach (what are the advantages) instead of using my approach?

Comment: Doing it this way is taking FULL Advantage of WPF. WPF it best utilized using Resources and Bindings. Ideally a great architected WPF application has minimal x:Name references and using the code-behind to update the GUI

Comment: Additional doing it my way will require you to JUST change the Resource Dictionary and that it. With your way you will have to Update EVERY control by hand in the code behind. Then if you add another you got to remember to add it. Then if you use DataTemplates it will be miserable to find these controls.